# Change Font Color in Keynote

Tags: keynote

I am creating a keynote presentation and pasted some text into the presentation.  It was white on black.  I was able to turn off the black ground by changing the "Fill" option but I don't know how to change the text color.

Here is what I see:

[image: Keynote style pane for text]

My question is: how to I change the text color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the "Text" tab, the color is the fifth control on that tab.

[image: Keynote text color control location on iphone]

[image: Keynote text color control location on MacOS]